# Gradle skipping task X as it has no source files

Tags: android, gradle

I have created a gradle.build that compiles an Android project. It is producing the correct APKs and as a post build step I want to copy them into another folder with a more meaningful name.

I have wrote this task to achieve this:

```
task copyBundle(type: Copy) {
    def versionCode = android.defaultConfig.versionCode
    def buildDate = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm")

    def outputFile = 'HexPath-android-release-' + buildDate + '-' + versionCode + '.apk'

    println "Copying file to " + outputFile

    from('HexPath-android/build/apk/')
    into('output/android/')
    include('HexPath-android-release.apk')
    rename ('HexPath-android-release.apk', outputFile)
}
```

The problem I am having is that it skips this task saying "Skipping task ':HexPath-android:copyBundle' as it has no source files.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

The from folder is correct and has several .apks.
The include filename is correct.
The output folder does not exist when the script is ran.
The rename is a valid filename.

Comment: Isn't `HexPath-android` the directory that contains the build script with this copy task? Also the task seems to be missing a task dependency on the task that produces the apk.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing that out. Looks like it was a case of using the wrong paths in the from function.

Answer (score 0):

You said the folder has several APK files, but here you are including only one possible file, which has to be named exactly 'HexPath-android-release.apk'. Do you have this file there?

If you want exactly this one file copied each time, then I'd suggest rewriting the end to something like this:

```
from('HexPath-android/build/apk/HexPath-android-release.apk') {
    rename { outpuFile }
}
into('output/android/')
```

But if you want multiple files copied, then revise your 'include' segment to have some wildcards, and make maybe a closure to create their output names. Hope this helps.

Also, isn't HexPath-android the project itself. Shouldn't the path start just from 'build...'?